# Why are '#' s in my extension not being dialed in Android?

Tags: android

Here is some code I am using to dial a phone number. It works fine, except for when I put a '#' in the extension. The ','s are to cause a delay before the extension is dialed. Why doesn't the '#' get dialed? Basically, any numbers after the # are just getting discarded.

```
String number = "555-555-5555,,1#123"
// # is not dialed, neither are 123
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:" + number);
Log.d("URI", uri.toString());
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#")` to send it with ACTION_CALL.

Answer (score 3):

> The character "#" is excluded because it is used to delimit a URI from
>   a fragment identifier in URI references

You need to use `Uri.encode(yourEncodeDailString)`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to replace the # with %23.