# Making a Phone Call with a Number Extension

Tags: android

I have code to allow a user to click a button to make a phone call:

```
public void addCallButton(){
    ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.callUsButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            call01();
        }
    });
}

private void call01(){
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
}
```

However, the number that needs to be dialed is `(123)456-789 ex. 123`

How do I add the extension number in the code?

Comment: What number would you use if you should save the number in the contacts?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE` or `PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT`? You would have to put either one of them in front of the extension number.

So it would be

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"+PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE+"#123"));
```

Comment: Thank! The PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE didn't do anything, but the PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT worked.  Kind of strange though, it prompts you to dial in the set extension number instead of automatically doing it.  Is there a way for it to automatically dial the extension number for you? Or is this the only code available for this kind of thing?  The .PAUSE code worked, just wondering if it's possible to do it this way.

Comment: Did some further digging and found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586216/why-are-s-in-my-extension-not-being-dialed-in-android). Presumably, because the pound symbol isn't included, it doesn't work properly. Could you try adding the symbol to see if it will work?

Comment: PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT worked for ACTION_CALL but not for ACTION_DIAL. Any idea how it can be done with ACTION_DIAL?